How to remove figure captions in Quarto-R Markdown without breaking cross-references
I have another very basic question to reference a figure in Quarto using R, which I could not find an answer to it online.
So, here is very minimal reproducible example;
---
title: "Untitled"
format: pdf
editor: visual
---

```{r fig-plot, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE, echo=FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
mtcars <- mtcars

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = cyl)) +
  geom_point()

As can be seen in @fig-plot

The resulting output is

As can be seen from the output, there is a text under the figure, which I do not want to have. How can I remove it without breaking the plot's cross-reference? Thank you for your kind attention beforehand.

Option 1: remove fig from chunk label
Your reprex was missing closing fence on the code chunk. With that fixed, simply removing the fig portion will remove the caption text below the figure. You also don't need fig.cap: false in the YAML frontmatter.
The fig section in the chunk label flags for quarto that this is a figure. See the documentation here. By omitting fig, the caption is removed. This does not solve the broken cross reference, but it isn't clear from the question what you want to do with that.
Additionally, as per the documentation, one can move the chunk options down into the chunk itself.
---
title: "Untitled"
format: pdf
editor: visual
---



```{r}
#| label: plot
#| warning: false
#| message: false
#| echo: false
library(tidyverse)
mtcars <- mtcars

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = cyl)) +
  geom_point()
```

Output:

Option 2 set fig-cap to blank
Another approach is to set the chunk options to have a blank figure caption. This will keep the figure label, and the cross reference will work properly. However, if the desire is to remove all figure label information (which will break the cross-reference) option #1 is probably better.

```{r}
#| label: fig-plot
#| fig-cap: ""
#| warning: false
#| message: false
#| echo: false

library(tidyverse)
mtcars <- mtcars

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = cyl)) +
  geom_point()
```


Output:

Option 3 Put title in caption and place caption above figure.
Comments indicate the desire to reference a figure by its title. To my knowledge, quarto cross references require some type of figure label so that there is an entity that is being cross referenced. In option 3, the plot title can be placed in the figure caption and the caption moved to the top of the figure.
---
title: "Untitled"
format: pdf
editor: visual
fig-cap-location: top
---

```{r}
#| label: fig-plot
#| fig-cap: "Plot Title"
#| warning: false
#| message: false
#| echo: false

library(tidyverse)
mtcars <- mtcars

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = cyl)) +
  geom_point()
```


Output:


Thank you for your time and suggestions. Yes, you are right that my question might be ambiguous. Actually, what I would like to achieve at the end is the first option but with a working cross-reference, not a broken. Could you suggest please a solution for that? Thank you in advance.

I'm not clear what one would cross reference to if not a figure label or some other identifier. If the figure has no label, to what would it be cross referenced? Alternately, one could just write Figure 1. However, that would still leave readers unclear as to what figure 1 was especially if the document contains multiple figures. Note also that Quarto offers several options for figure label placement.

So, I thought maybe there can be a figure/plot label option so that one can only have a cross-reference for each plot, which does not necessarily lead to a figure/plot text&caption because I think I have a title for each plot so I do not think that having a figure caption is a necessary option. So, I hope I am clear on what I want to achieve.

See option 3. I do not think it is possible to create a cross-reference without a label. As I understand them, cross-references reference labels--not titles. Hack this by putting the title text in the figure caption (Option 3). Labels help readers understand what is referenced. In the end, for a lower friction experience, I strongly advise using the cross-referencing tools as they are intended  (i.e. option 2 but with text in the fig-cap string). If the answer (and comments) provided insight on your issue, kindly upvote. Good luck.

Also, for the reprex there is no need to load the entire tidyverse as only ggplot2 is used

I do really thank you so much for your comments. Although that was not something I was looking for (I am still looking for a solution, where there will be no automatically generated text/title for the plot but I will be able to cross-reference the plot though), I will upvote the answer you provided as you really spared lots of time to figure out a solution for my problem. Thank you so much.
